# Call a function within format syntax

Tags: powershell

I have written code below to get the processor count.

```powershell
Function cpucount {

Get-WmiObject Win32_processor | select -Expand NumberOfLogicalProcessors | Unique

} 

Function cpumodel {

'cpu: $(cpucount) X {0:0}' -f ( Get-WmiObject Win32_processor | select -Expand Name | Unique )

}
```

Trouble is, I want the code to display the below output. The number of processors and the model of the processor.

```powershell
cpu:4 X Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU L7555 @ 1.87GHz
```

Right now, it is giving me the following output when I call my code, mainly function named cpumodel through a switch statement.

```powershell
PS C:\Users\Administrator> .\test.ps1 cpu
cpu: $(cpucount) X Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           L7555  @ 1.87GHz
```

How can I call the cpucount function inside my format syntax in cpumodel function or How will I be able to achieve my desired result? Finally, How avoid the spaces in the following output?

```powershell
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           L7555  @ 1.87GHz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single-quoted string literals do not process sub-expressions (stuff inside `$(...)`).  PowerShell always treats them as just literal text.

You need to use a double-quoted string literal instead:

```powershell
"cpu: $(cpucount) X {0:0}" -f ( Get-WmiObject Win32_processor | select -Expand Name | Unique )
^                        ^
```

As for the extra spaces, they are a part of the value returned by the call to `Get-WmiObject`. So, you'll need to remove them yourself from the value. This can be done easily with the `-replace` operator:

```powershell
Function cpumodel {

$data = Get-WmiObject Win32_processor | select -Expand Name | Unique
$data = $data -replace '\s+', ' '
"cpu: $(cpucount) X {0:0}" -f $data

}
```

Comment: That works! Thank you. Any way to avoid all the spaces in my output?